# Web Api in .net core can't find required service for GraphQL

Tags: c#, graphql

I have an api that I am working on and I keep running into this error:

> InnerException
> {"Required service for type GraphQL.Types.InterfaceGraphType1[CardSortApiV3.Domain.DTO.ContactDTO] not found"}  System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

I have the following code in their respective files:
**StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();
    services.AddScoped<IDocumentWriter, DocumentWriter>();
    services.AddScoped<ProjectQuery>();
    services.AddScoped<ContactQuery>();
    services.AddScoped<MainQuery>();
    services.AddScoped<ProjectType>();
    services.AddScoped<ContactType>();
    services.AddScoped<ContactDTO>();
    services.AddScoped<ISchema, GraphQLProjectSchema>();
    services.AddDbContext<cardsortsoftwaresContext>();
    services.AddScoped<IProjectService, ProjectService>();
    services.AddScoped<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
}
```

**ContactQuery.cs**

```
public class ContactQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public ContactQuery()
    {
        int id = 0;
        Field<ListGraphType<ContactType>>(
            name: "contacts", resolve: context =>
            {
                return /*projectService.GetProjects()*/ null;
            });
        Field<ContactType>(
            name: "project",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "id" }),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                id = (int)context.Arguments["id"].Value;
                return /*projectService.GetProjectById(id)*/ null;
            });
    }
}
```

**ProjectQuery.cs**

```
public class ProjectQuery : ObjectGraphType<object>
{
    public ProjectQuery(IProjectService projectService)
    {
        Name = "Query";
        int id = 0;
        Field<ListGraphType<ProjectType>>(
            name: "projects", resolve: context =>
            {
                return projectService.GetProjects();
            });
        Field<ProjectType>(
            name: "project",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "id" }),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                id = (int)context.Arguments["id"].Value;
                return projectService.GetProjectById(id);
            });
    }
}
```

**MainQuery.cs**

```
public MainQuery()
{
    Field<ProjectQuery>("projects", resolve:context =>
    {
        return new {};
    });
    Field<ContactQuery>("contacts", resolve: context =>
    {
        return new {};
    });
}
```

**Schema.cs**

```
public class GraphQLProjectSchema:Schema, ISchema
{
    public GraphQLProjectSchema(IServiceProvider resolver):base(resolver)
    {
        Query = resolver.GetService<MainQuery>();
    }
}
```

I have spent the last 4 hours researching and searching for answers but nothing works. Everything works up until I try and add in a linked `Contact` to a `Project`.

Any help would be seriously appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I realized this morning that it might help if I provided the type files as well.

**ContactType.cs**

```
public class ContactType : ObjectGraphType<ContactDTO>
{
    public ContactType()
    {
        Name = "Contact";
        Field(_ => _.Id).Description("Contact Id");
        Field(_ => _.FullName).Description("Contact Name");
        Field(_ => _.Email).Description("Contact Email");
        Field(_ => _.Phone).Description("Phone number for contact");
    }
}
```

**ProjectType.cs**

```
public class ProjectType : ObjectGraphType<ProjectDTO>
{
    public ProjectType()
    {
        Name = "Project";
        Field(_ => _.Id).Description("Project Id");
        Field(_ => _.Title).Description("Project Title");
        Field(_ => _.Description).Description("Project Description");
        Field(_ => _.ConfirmationCode).Description("Project Confirmation Code");
        Field(_ => _.Options).Description("Project Options (\"As a comma separated list\")");
        Field(_ => _.ProjectStatus).Description("Project Status (\"As an integer\")");
        Field(_ => _.CreatedTime).Description("Project Creation Time");
        Field(_ => _.UpdatedTime).Description("Project Update Time");
        Field(_ => _.EstimatedCompletion).Description("Estimated Completion Date");
        Field<InterfaceGraphType<ContactDTO>>("contact", "The contact that requested this project");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there multiple definitions of `ContactDTO`? Adding the wrong one perhaps?

Comment: @JHBonarius No, There is only one definition for `ContactDTO`

Comment: For reference it breaks on the last `Field` call in `ProjectType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer though it didn't seem like it was going to work at first.

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentWriter, DocumentWriter>();
        services.AddScoped<ProjectQuery>();
        services.AddScoped<ContactQuery>();
        services.AddScoped<MainQuery>();
        services.AddScoped<ProjectType>();
        services.AddScoped<ContactType>(); // This was already provided
        services.AddScoped<ISchema, GraphQLProjectSchema>();
        services.AddDbContext<cardsortsoftwaresContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IProjectService, ProjectService>();
        services.AddScoped<IProjectRepository, ProjectRepository>();
    }
```

Then in **ProjectType.cs**

```
    public ProjectType()
    {
        Name = "Project";
        Field(_ => _.Id).Description("Project Id");
        Field(_ => _.Title).Description("Project Title");
        Field(_ => _.Description).Description("Project Description");
        Field(_ => _.ConfirmationCode).Description("Project Confirmation Code");
        Field(_ => _.Options).Description("Project Options (\"As a comma separated list\")");
        Field(_ => _.ProjectStatus).Description("Project Status (\"As an integer\")");
        Field(_ => _.CreatedTime).Description("Project Creation Time");
        Field(_ => _.UpdatedTime).Description("Project Update Time");
        Field(_ => _.EstimatedCompletion).Description("Estimated Completion Date");
        /* Notice here that I am now requesting ContactType rather than ObjectGraphType<ContactDTO>*/
        Field<ContactType>("contact", "The contact that requested this project");
    }
```

Because I had provided Contact type to the `ConfigureServices` method, DI was able to resolve it. I can't say for sure that I understand why it works but I do know that in order to provide a link from one type to another you want to request them directly as the types that are provided in `ConfigureServices`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're using GraphQL for fetching data? you may take a look [NReco.GraphQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NReco.GraphQL/) to do it from the box. There's no need to configure classes/resolvers for each schema definition (enough just define it once in the JSON file).